# How do I pass my click handler from parent to children correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck trying to refactor my scoreboard component because I can't pass click handlers from parent to child correctly. What am I doing wrong?

This is my component structure

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function ScoreBoard(props) {
  return (
    <section className="scoreboard">
      <div className="topRow">
        <div className="home">
          <h2 className="home__name">{props.data.home.name}</h2>
          <div className="home__score">{props.data.home.score}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="timer">00:03</div>
        <div className="away">
          <h2 className="away__name">{props.data.away.name}</h2>
          <div className="away__score">{props.data.away.score}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <BottomRow />
    </section>
  );
}

function TDButton(props) {
  return (
    <button className={props.side + "Buttons__touchdown"}>
      {props.side.toUpperCase() + " Touchdown"}
    </button>
  );
}

function FGButton(props) {
/* similar to TDButton */
}

function Buttons(props) {
  let scoreCounter = props.scoreCounter;
  return (
    <section className="buttons">
      <div className="homeButtons">
        <TDButton side="home" onClick={scoreCounter("Lions", 7)} />
        <TDButton side="away" onClick={scoreCounter("Tigers", 7)} />
      </div>
      <div className="awayButtons">
        <FGButton side="home" onClick={scoreCounter("Lions", 3)} />
        <FGButton side="away" onClick={scoreCounter("Tigers", 3)} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

function App() {
  const data = {
    home: { name: "Lions", score: 32 },
    away: { name: "Tigers", score: 32 }
  };
  const [homeScore, sethomeScore] = useState(data.home.score);
  const [awayScore, setawayScore] = useState(data.away.score);

  const scoreCounter = (team, amount) => {
    if (team === data.home.name) {
      console.log("in");
      sethomeScore(homeScore + amount);
    } else {
      console.log("out");
      setawayScore(awayScore + amount);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ScoreBoard data={data} />
      <Buttons data={data} scoreCounter={() => scoreCounter} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The initial component all lived in App so I am trying to break it into smaller components. I can't seem to get the click handler to work though. What am I doing wrong? Maybe my component breakdown could be improved? Thanks!

Comment: `onClick={scoreCounter("Lions", 7)}` calls the function and assigns the result. You need `onClick={() => scoreCounter("Lions", 7)}`

Comment: still doesn't work. shouldn't that be taken care of inside App? `<Buttons data={data} scoreCounter={() => scoreCounter} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You adding props to TButton but you don't use it inside. Use something like this:

```
function TDButton(props) {
  return (
    <button className={props.side + "Buttons__touchdown"} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.side.toUpperCase() + " Touchdown"}
    </button>
  );
}
```

so it's like:

```
    <TDButton side="home" onClick={scoreCounter("Lions", 7)} />

    <button className={props.side + "Buttons__touchdown"} onClick={scoreCounter("Lions", 7)}>
      {props.side.toUpperCase() + " Touchdown"}
    </button>
```

because you're passing the props to event from parent.

but this will only work if scoreCounter("Lions", 7) return a function, if it's regular function that do action you need:

```
<TDButton side="home" onClick={() => scoreCounter("Lions", 7)} />
```

so props is a function not the value that function return.

Also this maybe not what you want:

```
<Buttons data={data} scoreCounter={() => scoreCounter} />
```

scoreCounter will be function that return value of function (that answer previous consern but you really want normal function, because above function don't have params and you use 'Lion' that will be ignored):

```
<Buttons data={data} scoreCounter={scoreCounter} />
```

Answer (score 0):

SO you've to call the function in your JSX

```
<Buttons data={data} scoreCounter={() => scoreCounter()} />
```

You can pass value into the function if required.